# Laravel 5 - Unknown Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I'm trying to make a login form in laravel 5.

Everytime I try to log in I get the error

> PDOException in Connector.php line 55: SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown
>   database 'php2project'

However the database exists.
[image]

I could use "php artisan migrate" without any problem, so I have no idea why I'm having this issue right now.

here's how my .env file looks

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=_STACK_

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=php2project
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=_STACK_

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

EDIT: Here is my config/database information

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Database Connections
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
| Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
| supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
|
|
| All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
| so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
| choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
|
*/

'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlite',
        'database' => database_path('database.sqlite'),
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver'   => 'pgsql',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
        'schema'   => 'public',
    ],

    'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],

],
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use View;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class LogInController extends Controller 
{
    public function showLogin()
    {
        return View::make('login.login');
    }

    public function doLogin()
    {
        // validate
        $rules = array(
            'email'    => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:3'
        );
        // run the validation rules on the inputs from the form
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        // if the validator fails, redirect back to the form
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::to('login')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
        } else {
            // create our user data for the authentication
            $userdata = array(
                'email'     => Input::get('email'),
                'password'  => Input::get('password')
            );
            // attempt to do the login
            if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {

                // validation successful!
                // redirect them to the secure section or whatever
                // return Redirect::to('secure');
                // for now we'll just echo success (even though echoing in a controller is bad)
                echo 'SUCCESS!';

            } else {        

                // validation not successful
                return Redirect::to('login');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**view**

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('title', 'Login')
@section('content')

{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'login')) !!}
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <p>
        {!! $errors->first('email') !!}
        {!! $errors->first('password') !!}
    </p>

    <p>
        {!! Form::label('email', 'Email Address') !!}
        {!! Form::text('email', Input::old('email'), array('placeholder' => 'john@snow.com')) !!}
    </p>

    <p>
        {!! Form::label('password', 'Password') !!}
        {!! Form::password('password') !!}
    </p>

    <p>{!! Form::submit('Submit!') !!}</p>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of: `app/config/database.php` ?

Comment: Which environment you are working on?

Comment: @Daan updated the OP

Comment: Seems like your database configuration is fine. Can you post the model/view/controller in which you try to access the database ?

Comment: Are you running this via `php artisan serve` by any chance? And did you make any changes to the `.env` file after the `serve` command was already started?

Comment: @Daan updated the post

Comment: @bodgan I don't think so, anyway to check this? (never used php artisan serve afaik)

Comment: Ok, I wanted to see if you might have the environment values cached, and you've made changes to them that weren't reflected. But that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I see your using laravel's `auth` can you see if in `app/config/auth.php` the driver is set to eloquent or database ? If eloquent than can you post the User model ?

Comment: @Daan config/auth: [AUTH](http://pastebin.com/7QPMCfha) and here's the full error incase it can help [ERROR](http://pastebin.com/fLcfbgWr)

Comment: Are the credentials in this stackoverflow the one you use in your project? In that case it's not using the corrent `.env` file.

Comment: yes it is, I changed password and appkey ofc on stack

Comment: @Daan anyway to fix this then? It's the only .env file in my project

Comment: Run `dd(config('database'));` in your auth controller and show us the result.

Answer (score 1):

First check if Correct Credentials are set in .evn

If yes then try caching the config. Sometime issue may occur because you made change in .env but didnt cache it(Only if you are caching configs in your project).

try by running `php artisan cache:config`

Answer (score -1):

It seems like your **database** is set to **forge** in **config->database.php** whereas database name in **.env** file is **php2project**. Make sure they are same in both files, also **password** is blank in config->database.php but is set to _STACK_ in .env file and also make sure that your **username** is same in both files.